# Why do we use expectancy of an estimator when calculating bias?

Tags: statistics

Formula for calculating bias is: $Bias(\widehat{f}(x))=E(\widehat{f}(x_{0}))-f(x_{0})$

But $\widehat{f}(x)$ is a function, so it has a value. Why we take expected value of a constant?

I know it is a basic question but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: When you are talking about bias, $\widehat{f}(x)$ is an estimator (not treated as an estimate here) of the (parametric) function $f(x)$.

Comment: Estimator is sample of function f(x) right? So isn't it supposed to have still a value as a result? Or I may have a miss understanding about estimators, in that case I would be glad if you point it out.

Comment: Estimator is a function of the sample $x$. An *estimate* of $f(x)$ would have a value calculated from the observed sample, but estimator is effectively a random quantity.